# phoneGap ios build with push what cert?

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a short and perhaps easy-to-answer question.

I am done with my IOS app that contains push notifications.

What certificate should I build the distribution app with (export to .p12 and use)?
Right now I have two.. one called:

**"iOS Distribution"**

And another called:

**"Apple Push Services"**

I have tried with both. But only  **iOS Distribution** Cert works.

The other one gives me this error:

> Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching

So the big question:
Should I use the Apple Push Service cert - and did I do something wrong along the way since its not working?

Or should I use the IOS Distribution cert?

Comment: You should iOS distribution cert to create the build. Apple Push Service cert is only for push notification(Not using for creating build). On your provisioning profile push notification should be enabled.

Comment: Thanks alot!.
That's the answer I was looking for.